# How to automatically add other library when I create a project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project-template

When I create a C# Console Project in Visual Studio, only `using System;` is imported.

How to automatically import the below while creating a Project?

```
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
```

Comment: You may want to look at creating your own project templates https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396